# Visual Studio 2015: access denied on FeedCache

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2015, permissions, access-denied

when I try to open a project in VS 2015 I get the error "Access denied" on a File located in ‪C:\Users\XY\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\FeedCache .

The german message is "C:\Users\XY\Documents\Visual Studio 2015\Projects\App1\App1\App1.csproj : error  : Der Zugriff auf den Pfad "C:\Users\XY\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\FeedCache\Feed-969FF52C4894C164-File.xml" wurde verweigert."

Some hours ago I restarted my computer for system updates and immediately after that I installed the english language pack for VS.

So I navigated to that FeedCache folder. For that Folder I have all permissions an the security settings grant me al privileges even for inherited files and folders ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CUOVV.png)). But when i, for example, try to rename a file inside that FeedCache folder, I get a access denied Message. So for me it seems to be a matter of wrong previlegs.

I've tried to disable Inheritance for the FeedCache Folder and the to re-enable it. But I get an error during enableing ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ekBPm.png)).

Kim

Comment: Are you a local admin on the machine?

Comment: It's my private device. So i use my Microsoft-Account as User and this user tries to open Projects in VS.

Comment: After hours of trial & error, I just renamed the whole folder. When i then started VS, a new folder with the needed Files was created. Senns to be a dirty Solution.

Comment: Hi quaxdachs! Please write down your solution and accept it as answer for others to find. (And to keep this question from staying unanswered :))